# Inheriting the class dictionary with metaclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

I am setting a class property `fields` using a metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict):

        clsdict['fields'] = {k: v
                             for k, v in clsdict.items()
                             if <my_condition>}
        return super(MyMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict)

class MyBaseClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    fields = {}
```

The following instantiation leads to expected results:

```
class SubClass(MyBaseClass):
    param1 = 1 # meets <my_condition>

>>> SubClass.fields
{param1: 1}
```

But if I now subclass `SubClass`, `fields` is empty:

```
class SubSubClass(SubClass):
   pass

>>> SubSubClass.fields 
{}
```

How would I be able to update the classdict of all classes in inheritance hierarchy so that the `fields` variable would be updated from base classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to somehow keep the `fields` of the superclasses, for example by iterating over the "bases" and using their `fields` as starting point:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict):
        if 'fields' not in clsdict:
            clsdict['fields'] = {}
        # Initialize "fields" from base classes
        for base in bases:
            try:
                clsdict['fields'].update(base.fields)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        # Fill in new fields (I included a "trivial" condition here, just use yours instead.)
        clsdict['fields'].update({k: v for k, v in clsdict.items() if k.startswith('param')})
        return super(MyMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict)
```

And it works for `SubClass` and `SubSubClass`:

```
>>> SubClass.fields
{'param1': 1}

>>> SubSubClass.fields
{'param1': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. The only question: why the `try/except` on `clsdict['fields'].update(base.fields`? You already set `fields` on the base class if it is missing.

Comment: @ProfHase85: Because a subclass can have multiple base classes and some of those may not have a `fields` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest turning `fields` into a property descriptor which fetches all the contents of `_fields` from parent classes. This way you can also more easily customize what happens when there are name conflicts, etc.

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict):
        # change fields to _fields
        clsdict['_fields'] = {k: v
                             for k, v in clsdict.items()
                             if <my_condition>}
        return super(MyMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict)
    @property
    def fields(cls):
        # reversed makes most recent key value override parent values
        return {k:v 
                for c in reversed(cls.__mro__) 
                for k,v in getattr(c, '_fields', {}).items() }
```

Usage:

```
class MyBaseClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    fields = {}

class SubClass(MyBaseClass):
    param1 = 1

>>> SubClass.fields
{param1: 1}

class SubSubClass(SubClass):
   pass

>>> SubSubClass.fields 
{param1: 1} # success
```

Now, usage of `SomeChildClass.fields` always refers to the metaclass property. The third argument to `getattr` allows classes with no `_fields` attribute (such as `object`) to fail silently.

Using a descriptor also has the advantage of preventing a child class from accidentally overriding the `fields` attribute:

```
>>> SubSubClass.fields = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You could also create a setter, if desired, and use it in the `__init__` method (i.e., go back to using `fields` instead of `_fields`) so that the entirety rest of the class is implementation agnostic:

```
    @fields.setter
    def fields(cls, mapping):
        try:
            cls._fields.update(**mapping)
        except AttributeError:
            cls._fields = dict(**mapping)
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, since it provides a live view of updated attributes. But you could make use of  `collections.ChainMap` set-up in the `cls.fields` attribute straight in the metaclass. This way one does not need to create the dictionary view you do on every attribute access in your `fields` property,